# convert time series with 15 min in pandas using statistical or any other method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a time series in pandas that looks like this:

time = [Timestamp('2021-01-01 05:30:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 05:40:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 05:50:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:00:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:10:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:20:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:30:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:40:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:50:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 07:00:00')]

value = [4.84,6.92,7.99,8.01,7.07,5.11,7.1,7.03,7.02,8.07]

I would like to convert time series with 15 min times steps,is resampling correct method? or any other method(statistical or any ) is available?
suppose there is any missing data,how can we handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, use [`Resampler.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.mean.html):

```
s = pd.Series(value, index=time)
print (s.resample('15Min').mean())
2021-01-01 05:30:00    5.880
2021-01-01 05:45:00    7.990
2021-01-01 06:00:00    7.540
2021-01-01 06:15:00    5.110
2021-01-01 06:30:00    7.065
2021-01-01 06:45:00    7.020
2021-01-01 07:00:00    8.070
Freq: 15T, dtype: float64
```

Or if need [`Series.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) - only `15Min` values are extracted:

```
print (s.asfreq('15Min'))
2021-01-01 05:30:00    4.84
2021-01-01 05:45:00     NaN
2021-01-01 06:00:00    8.01
2021-01-01 06:15:00     NaN
2021-01-01 06:30:00    7.10
2021-01-01 06:45:00     NaN
2021-01-01 07:00:00    8.07
Freq: 15T, dtype: float64


print (s.asfreq('15Min', method='ffill'))
2021-01-01 05:30:00    4.84
2021-01-01 05:45:00    6.92
2021-01-01 06:00:00    8.01
2021-01-01 06:15:00    7.07
2021-01-01 06:30:00    7.10
2021-01-01 06:45:00    7.03
2021-01-01 07:00:00    8.07
Freq: 15T, dtype: float64
```

> suppose there is any missing data,how can we handle this.

Sample data with missing values:

```
Timestamp = pd.Timestamp
time = [Timestamp('2021-01-01 05:30:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 05:40:00'),
        Timestamp('2021-01-01 05:50:00'), Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:10:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:20:00'),
        Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:30:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:40:00'),
        Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:50:00'),Timestamp('2021-01-01 07:00:00')]

value = [4.84,np.nan,np.nan,8.01,7.07,5.11,7.1,7.03,7.02,8.07]
s = pd.Series(value, index=time)
print (s)
2021-01-01 05:30:00    4.84
2021-01-01 05:40:00     NaN
2021-01-01 05:50:00     NaN
2021-01-01 06:00:00    8.01
2021-01-01 06:10:00    7.07
2021-01-01 06:20:00    5.11
2021-01-01 06:30:00    7.10
2021-01-01 06:40:00    7.03
2021-01-01 06:50:00    7.02
2021-01-01 07:00:00    8.07
dtype: float64
```

If need replace missing values is possible use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `mean` of all values of original `Series`:

```
print (s.resample('15Min').mean())
2021-01-01 05:30:00    4.840
2021-01-01 05:45:00      NaN
2021-01-01 06:00:00    7.540
2021-01-01 06:15:00    5.110
2021-01-01 06:30:00    7.065
2021-01-01 06:45:00    7.020
2021-01-01 07:00:00    8.070
Freq: 15T, dtype: float64

print (s.resample('15Min').mean().fillna(s.mean()))
2021-01-01 05:30:00    4.84000
2021-01-01 05:45:00    6.78125
2021-01-01 06:00:00    7.54000
2021-01-01 06:15:00    5.11000
2021-01-01 06:30:00    7.06500
2021-01-01 06:45:00    7.02000
2021-01-01 07:00:00    8.07000
Freq: 15T, dtype: float64
```

If use second method `asfreq` not fill missing values from original data:

```
print (s.asfreq('15Min', method='ffill'))
2021-01-01 05:30:00    4.84
2021-01-01 05:45:00     NaN
2021-01-01 06:00:00    8.01
2021-01-01 06:15:00    7.07
2021-01-01 06:30:00    7.10
2021-01-01 06:45:00    7.03
2021-01-01 07:00:00    8.07
Freq: 15T, dtype: float64
```